# How can I check if a bracket is opened at one line and closed in another line in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a little program to check if there's an error with tabulation and brackets but for the brackets I can only check in one line. How can I check if it's opened and closed in multiple lines? (like () [] {} )
And have the line number where is the error of the file where I've take the string?

I've tried to check in one line and it works but if I have a bracket that opens in line 3 and closes in line 4 it returns me like if there's an error.

```py
def brackets():
    init = 0
    finish = 0
    err = []
    
    with open(sys.argv[1], "rt") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for l in lines:
            for ch in str(l):
                if ch == "(":
                    init += 1
                elif ch == ")":
                    finish += 1

            if init == finish:
                if "-a" in sys.argv:
                    print( "[OK] " + str(lines.index(l) + 1 ) + ": " + str(l.strip("\n")) )
            else:
                if "-a" in sys.argv:
                    print( "[ERR] " + str(lines.index(l) + 1 ) + ": " + str(l.strip("\n")) )
                err.append( ["b", str(lines.index(l)), str(l)] )

            init = 0
            finish = 0
```

I expect that returns me errors only when a bracket is opened and not closed in the whole file.

for example if I have a string like this:

```
a = [ "hello",
      "world!"]

def hello():
    print("hello world")
```

It should be balanced because I've opened and closed the square brackets, not in the same line but I've opened and closed those brackets

but in this case there should be an error

```
a = [ "hello",
      "world!"

def hello():
    print("hello world"
```

because I've opened those brackets but I've not closed them in any line

Comment: Could you provide a few examples of inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180567/checking-for-balanced-brackets-in-python/195800#195800

Comment: @Xosrov I'm sorry, I noticed now that the formatting was wrong, fixed it and added the right examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
# read the file as a whole
with open( 'somefile.txt' ) as fin :
    text = fin.read()

# filter everything but brackets out
brackets = ''.join( [i for i in text if i in '{}[]()'] )

# remove balanced pairs while we can
while len(brackets) > 0 :
    new_brackets = brackets.replace( '()', '').replace( '{}', '').replace( '[]', '')

    if brackets == new_brackets : break # no changes, bail out

    brackets = new_brackets

if len(brackets) :
    print 'unbalanced', brackets
else :
    print 'balanced'
```

The code above considers the following `[(])` as `unbalanced`, because of the wrong order. If you don't care about the order, you may just count opening and closing ones, and make sure the number is the same:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('[[]][[)()(}}')
Counter({'[': 4, ')': 2, '(': 2, ']': 2, '}': 2})
```

Comment: If I have a file where I take the string how can I have the line number where the bracket is opened but not closed?

Comment: @Ax34 instead of simple string containing the brackets, you may use the list of tuples, like `( '{', 23 )`, which means the opening bracket was in line 23. then you iterate over that list removing pairs of open/close brackets and see what's left. not a one-liner, but similar idea to what I did.